# Spring jpa Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory error while trying to configure datasource

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository of username/passwords which I am trying to configure into spring web security using a customUserDetailsService. My base package is called 'showcase'.

I have a  WebSecurityConfiguration as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource datasource;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource)
                .and()
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);

        // @formatter:on
    }
```

I am trying to configure this datasource as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "showcase"
})
public class DatabaseConfig {
//@Resource
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutibodb");
    dataSource.setUsername("db");
    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("showcase");

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT,"showcase.MySQLDialect");
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,"create-drop");
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY,"org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,false);
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,true);


    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

The SQLDialect configuration is as follows:

```
public class MySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
@Override
public String getDropSequenceString(String sequenceName) {

    return "drop sequence if exists " + sequenceName;
}

@Override
public boolean dropConstraints() {

    return false;
}
```

I get an error which primarily says that: `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`.

I am new to Spring and must be missing something. I am not using any xml based config and wish to stick to only java config. I can share details of the rest of my code if required.

**Update:**
Here is my CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
AppUserRepository repository;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;


private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    logger.info("username:"+name);
            AppUser u = repository.findByUserName(name);
    if (u == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User details not found with this username: " + name);
    String username = u.getUsername();
    String password = u.getPassword();
    List authList = new ArrayList();
    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));

    User user = new User(username, password, authList);

    return user;
}
```

The UserService mentioned above saves a user in the AppUserRepository. The AppUser is an entity.

```
The entire error is:
2014-12-28 12:02:59.555  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}

2014-12-28 12:02:59.557  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

2014-12-28 12:02:59.560  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

2014-12-28 12:02:59.722  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}

2014-12-28 12:02:59.753  WARN 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mutibodb

2014-12-28 12:02:59.760  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: showcase.MySQLDialect

2014-12-28 12:02:59.767  INFO 5220 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null

2014-12-28 12:02:59.835 ERROR 5220 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private showcase.CustomUserDetailsService showcase.WebSecurityConfiguration.customUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: showcase.AppUserRepository showcase.CustomUserDetailsService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#165fa72a' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#165fa72a': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [showcase/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

I had not focused on the hibernate errors before. I guess my hibernate config is wrong. But is there a way of doing this without injecting the datasource? When I did not have the datasource field in the securrity config and was only using auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService), I was getting a `No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined` error. Trying to fix that lead me to this path.

Comment: Where is realization CustomUserDetailsService? Carefully read exception, can't autowire CustomUserDetailsService.

Comment: First of all your security config is faulty either you specify a custom userdetailsservice or inject the datasource, you cannot do both. Next you should inject a `UserDetailsService` as you should be programming to interfaces, not concrete classes. Is what you posted the full stack trace? I would expect a bit more information from hibernate.

Comment: I updated with more info. Could you please take a look. It would be helpful if this can be fixed without having to inject a datasource

Comment: You have a field of type `DataSource` which is then required, remove the field.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed my code and the updated parts are at http://pastebin.com/uh3f3kXz. Could you please take a look. I still seems to be getting an error that says `Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined`. I have updated the complete error there too.

Comment: Sorry, the complete error is in the same link...Did not update above to not create confusion...

Comment: You aren't really working with the framework, you are trying to work around it. Use the framework...

Comment: First off all read my comments, judging by what you posted on pastebin you didn't apply everything I mentioned. Judging from the error you don't have a datasource configured but are configuring dataacces in your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I finally got it working. I removed the datasource injection completely.  I sort of followed this example: https://github.com/scratches/jpa-method-security-sample/tree/master/src/main I am able to add signed up users at runtime now but i think it is using an in memory database so the added users get erased on server restart. If I want them to persist, what should be the approach? Would I need to configure a data source for that?